HttpOnly cookie in NextJS + Redux + Django API for storing JWT
I'm using NextJS in the frontend, Django API in the backend along with DRF and JWT for authentication and redux for state management.
Almost all of my routes requires authentication.
I'm able to store and access tokens in http-only cookies via NextJS routes API but since I'm using Redux too, all of my requests are going like this;
user request -> redux action -> nextjs route -> backend
Is this normal? I'd to implement nextjs route for each route just to access the http-only cookie and send it to backend endpoint as the route requires an authentication. This is tedious to implement and maintain, I've hundreds of routes.
Is there any other way I can achieve this efficiently?

I had the same problem with front-end, There is some ways to do that, I handle it in back-end side, I have routes for obtain token and refresh token, when the request comes to obtain token, I set the token on HTTP Only Cookie, same for refresh token, but in this way you can't use your back-end on sources other than web, this will couple your back-end with web, another way is to write your own API on NextJs that will request to the obtain token route in back-end, then store it on NextJs side, and each time you need a token call your NextJs API.
In this way you will decouple your front-end and back-end.
